Differences in Initializing Device Objects and Device Objects Index in Python
I am really confused and need help from community seeing this issue, I couldn't figure out where is the issue.
Python 3.10, on Macbook. The sig is a dict from json.
sig =load_json_data(f"signatures/{layer_2_stack}_device_signature.json")

The format of the json file. I think it should be fine and irrelevant.
{
  "HP": {
    "Eve": {
      "MotionSensor": {
        "Occupied": [
          "116,-90,79",
          "85,-90,79",
          "58,-90,79"
        ]
      },
...

My program use objects to do state tracking, and the following code snippet is the portion to do the init. I think the following two methods of code have expressed the same idea, but the outcome are different, specifically, the key of device_objects_idx are identical, but the values of device_objects might be different.
# Begin of Method A
device_objects = []
for controller in sig:
    for device_vendor in sig[controller]:
        for device_type in sig[controller][device_vendor]:
            device_objects.append(
                Device(device_vendor, device_type, sig[controller][device_vendor][device_type], True))

src_addr_set = set(frames["_ws.col.def_src"].unique())
device_objects_idx = {}
for addr in src_addr_set:
    device_objects_idx[addr] = device_objects.copy()
# End of Method A

# Begin of Method B
src_addr_set = set(frames["_ws.col.def_src"].unique())
device_objects_idx = {}
for addr in src_addr_set:
    device_objects = []
    for controller in sig:
        for device_vendor in sig[controller]:
            for device_type in sig[controller][device_vendor]:
                device_objects.append(
                    Device(device_vendor, device_type, sig[controller][device_vendor][device_type], True))
    device_objects_idx[addr] = device_objects
# End of Method B


# Begin of Method C
src_addr_set = set(frames["_ws.col.def_src"].unique())
device_objects_idx = {}
for addr in src_addr_set:
    device_objects_idx[addr] = []
    for controller in sig:
        for device_vendor in sig[controller]:
            for device_type in sig[controller][device_vendor]:
                device_objects_idx[addr].append(
                    Device(device_vendor, device_type, sig[controller][device_vendor][device_type], True))

# End of Method C

The method A given a dict of list of objects correctly, and the calculation afterwards given correct results. I want to move the logic inside the for loop so I can add the addr as a new parameter for the Device init, which is more complicated if I can only do method A. Neither the method B or C works.
The expected output is like,
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualLock @1715640334.165811
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualUnlock @1715640345.995737
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualLock @1715640355.334595
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualUnlock @1715640367.59393
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualLock @1715640376.808306
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualUnlock @1715640390.257182
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualLock @1715640398.881037
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualUnlock @1715640411.650251
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualLock @1715640420.21509
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualUnlock @1715640432.63086
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualLock @1715640442.74937
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualUnlock @1715640454.217029
Detected Event Yale Lock ManualLock @1715640463.624722

But Method B and Method C will cause, which is short on number of actual events, and not detecting the events correctly.
Detected Event Tuo Button LongPressing @1715639889.238013
Detected Event Tuo Button LongPressing @1715639889.425094
Detected Event Tuo Button LongPressing @1715639889.728248
Detected Event Tuo Button LongPressing @1715639889.90287
Detected Event Tuo Button LongPressing @1715639918.732685
Detected Event Tuo Button LongPressing @1715639918.741737
Detected Event Tuo Button LongPressing @1715639932.095897
Detected Event Tuo Button LongPressing @1715639945.629853
Detected Event Tuo Button LongPressing @1715640002.398402


Please refer [mcve]. What is sig ? Rather than describe it, can you show it? And the expected outputs?

Thank you for the response, I have updated the description. I am trying to create a minimal code snippet to replicate this issue.

I figured out, the shallow copy caused the issue. In such case, deepcopy is required.
